# Visiting Isla Incahuasi by public transportation

Tags: public-transport, transportation, bolivia, salar-de-uyuni

How does one get from Uyuni to Isla Incahuasi (in the middle of Salar de Uyuni) by public transportation?
I know it's doable to reach the salt lake, wikitravel states:

> there is also the option to just catch the local bus to Colchani (leaves from the street with all the bus company offices) for BOB10. Ask the driver/ayudante to let you off at the salt flats, and you can hike around for free to get a sense of the place. It takes about two hours to reach an old salt hotel.

I'm not sure if it's also possible to reach the Isla Incahuasi?

Answer (score 3):

Local buses don't have routes into the vast area of Salar de Uyuni, within which the Isla Incahuasi is located. The Salar de Uyuni is massive, over 4,000 square miles (10,582 sq. km).

Tours of the area start in Uyuni, at the edge of the Salar, and, of necessity, in a 4x4 vehicle that can navigate the terrain which, while flat, is often covered by a layer of water. Prices for a one-day tour in a 4x4 vehicle range from $30 USD to $60 USD.

While truly amazing during the day, the crepuscular sun rays are stunning, at either sunrise or sunset.